# Swift: Redirect to system settings text size

Tags: ios, swift, redirect, dynamic-text

Is there a way to redirect to settings page for so that user can set their dynamic font size? Using the code below redirect to the app settings page but there are no font size settings (is there a way to enable it?)

```
 let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Body Font Size",
                                                message: "Please proceed to Settings > Display & Brightness > Text Size to change your system font.",
                                                preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .Default) {
            (alertAction) in
            if let appSettings = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(appSettings)
            }
        }
        alertController.addAction(settingsAction)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```